# Reference in Constructor

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

Aloha :)

Is it possible to have a constructor with a reference as a parameter and then use that from another class?

```
    Class 1 named ABC
    function __construct( $table, $key, &$db ){

    $this->_tbl     = $table;
    $this->_tbl_key = $key;
    $this->_db      =& $db;
    $this->_pkey = $key;
}
```

Next I want to use ABC in XYZ. Like so:

```
    $ABC= new ABC("dummytable", "id");
```

But obviously this is missing a paramater and when I do enter a paramater it returns an error about reference..

How can I solve this?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$db` is object, then don't pass it as reference. If the parameter is optional, then give it a default value.

```
function __construct( $table, $key, $db = null){
    $this->_tbl     = $table;
    $this->_tbl_key = $key;
    $this->_db      = $db;
    $this->_pkey = $key;
}
```